# For faser searching, shouldn't one apply merge sort on the data before doing binary search or just jump straight to linear search?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, binary-search-tree, binary-search, mergesort

I'm learning about algorithms and have doubts about their application in certain situations. There is the divide and conquer merge sort, and the binary search. Both faster than linear growth algos.

Let's say I want to search for some value in a large list of data. I don't know whether the data is sorted or not. How about instead of doing a linear search, why not first do merge sort and then do binary search. Would that be faster? Or the process of applying merge sort and then binary search combined would slow it down even more than linear search? Why? Would it depend on the size of the data?

Comment: depends on how often you use the data. If you only ever will search it once, then a linear unsorted search will be cheaper, because you don't waste a ton of cpu on sorting the data. conversely, if you seach multiple times, then you'd have to determine the cost of a linear search v.s. the cost of sorting. at some point there'll be a crossover and search+sort will end up cheaper than search-only.

Comment: Sorting and searching are two totally different tasks. I'm not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a flaw in the premise of your question.  Merge Sort has O(N logN) complexity, which is the best any comparison-based sorting algorithm can be, but that's still a *lot* slower than a single linear scan.  Note that log<sub>2</sub>(1000) ~= 10.  (Obviously, the constant-factors matter a *lot*, esp. for smallish problem sizes.  Linear search of an array is one of the most efficient things a CPU can do.  Copying stuff around for MergeSort is not bad, because the loads and stores are from sequential addresses (so caches and prefetching are effective), but it's still a ton more work than 10 reads through the array.)

---

If you need to support a mix of insert/delete and query operations, all with good time complexity, pick the right data structure for the task.  A binary search tree is probably appropriate (or a Red-Black tree or some other variant that does some kind of rebalancing to prevent O(n) worst-case behaviour).  That'll give you O(log n) query, and O(log n) insert/delete.

- sorted array gives you O(n) insert/delete (because you have to shuffle the remaining elements over to make or close gaps), but O(log n) query (with lower time and space overhead than a tree).
- unsorted array: O(n) query (linear search), O(1) insert (append to the end),  O(n) delete (O(n) query, then shuffle elements to close the gap).  Efficient deletion of elements near the end.
- linked list, sorted or unsorted: few advantages other than simplicity.
- hash table: insert/delete: O(1) average (amortized).  query for present/not-present: O(1).  Query for which two elements a non-present value is between: O(n) linear scan keeping track of the min element greater than x, and max element less than x.

If your inserts/deletes happen in large chunks, then sorting the new batch and doing a merge-sort is much more efficient than adding elements one at a time to a sorted array.  (i.e. InsertionSort).  Adding a chunk at the end and doing QuickSort is also an option, and *might* modify less memory.

So the best choice depends on the access pattern you're optimizing for.

Comment: Thank you Peter. But since I'm new to the field, could you explain where I can learn more about this sentence that you mentioned?  `because the loads are stores are from sequential addresses (so caches and prefetching are effective)`. I don't understand the internals of that. Is there a quick easy to follow tutorial or article out there that talks about caches are memory utilization of algorithms etc?

Comment: @doublespeed:  oops, typo in that sentence (s/are/and/).  Ulrich Drepper's [What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf) is about 8 years old by now, so some of the stuff (esp. about using a prefetch thread) is outdated.  The basics of what caches are and how locality (in space (nearby addresses) and time (repeated access)) are still the same.  http://agner.org/optimize/ has stuff about optimizing asm and C++ for current x86 CPUs (and the C++ stuff is probably relevant to other architectures, too.)

Answer (score 1):

If the list is of size `n`, then

```
TimeOfMergeSort(list) + TimeOfBinarySearch(list) = O(n log n) + O(log n) = O(n log n)

TimeOfLinearSearch(list) = O(n)

O(n) < O(n log n)
```

Implies

```
TimeOfLinearSearch(list) < TimeOfMergeSort(list) + TimeOfBinarySearch(list)
```

Of course, as mentioned in the comments frequency of sorting and frequency of searching play a huge role in amortized cost.